# How to use perl to parse a text file

Tags: perl

I am new to perl,
I have text file contains 2 columns:

```
 lib1 cell1
 lib1 cell2
 lib2 cell3
 lib2 cell1
```

I would like to use perl to find there is duplicated in name in column 2 then print the name of column 1
In this text `cell1` is repeated 2 times.
I would like to have a report something like:

```
cell1 found in lib1 lib2
```

I use the code below to read and open the file

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

for my $file ( @ARGV ){

  open my$in_fh, '<', $file or die "could not open $file: $!\n";

  while( my $line = <$in_fh> ){
    chomp( $line );
    print "$line\n"
  }

}
```

But I don't know how to find the duplicated name in second column and print the 1st column

Comment: Is it intentional that the first `Lib1` has a upper case `L` and not lower case like the other rows, or is that a mistake?

Comment: There aren't any colons in your sample file?

Comment: @Shawn He means columns

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want to do here or what the data model is, but you would build some kind of hash. For example, for each line of input you would build a hash like `$hash{$col2}{$col1} = 1` and then you'll know the list of column1 values with `keys %{$hash{$col2}}` and the number of times column2 occurs with `scalar keys %{$hash{$col2}}`.  But this is just an educated guess unless you can clarify your question.

Comment: This isn't a free code writing service. Please show us the code you've tried, and the parts you're having problems with.

Comment: Thanks for responding,

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things here that Perl can do for you.

First, Perl will handle opening and reading the files you specify on the command line this the empty deadline operator (and here I'm using the [safer double diamond](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/05/use-perl-5-22s-operator-for-safe-command-line-handling/) version introduced in v5.22):

```
use v5.22
while( <<>> ) {
    ...
    }
```

Then, you can track what you've seen with a hash. Extract the columns, and use the interesting column as the key in the hash. Here I post-increment it's value. On the first go around, the post increment returns 0 (then increases the value by 1), so the conditional is false the first time. The next time it sees that same key, the value is true, so it warns:

```
use v5.22

my %Seen;
while( <<>> ) {
    chomp;
    my( $first, $second ) = split;
    if( $Seen{$second}++ ) {
         warn "Duplicated second column! Line $.\n";
         }
    }
```

The hash is a great way to track things that are strings instead of positions.

Now, you want to know which values in the first column appear with each value in the second. You could get a bit more fancy with that hash and make another level in the hash to store the first column. Perl automatically takes care of the details for you (and we have extended examples of this in [Intermediate Perl](https://www.intermediateperl.com).

First, accumulate the data in the hash:

```
use v5.22

my %Seen;
while( <<>> ) {
    chomp;
    my( $first, $second ) = split;
    $Seen{$second}{$first}++;
    }
```

Once you have the hash, you move on to the second step of reporting the data. All the values of the second column are the top level keys for the hash. With that key, get the second level of the hash, and get those keys, which are the first column:

```
foreach my $second ( keys %Seen ) {
    my @firsts = keys %{ $Seen{$second} };
    say "$second found in @firsts";
    }
```

With [v5.24's postfix dereferencing](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2016/04/postfix-dereferencing-is-stable-is-v5-24/), that's slightly cleaner since the dereference reads left to right rather than inside out:

```
use v5.24;
foreach my $second ( keys %Seen ) {
    my @firsts = keys $Seen{$second}->%*;
    say "$second found in @firsts";
    }
```

And, since the hash keys in the second level only appear once per value, you don't have duplicates.